# Can you have multiple vhosts defined while using mod_vhost_alias

Tags: apache-2.2

I've been using mod_vhost alias for a while not to allow me to capture my default server setup for any domains pointing to my hosting providers.

Now I would also like to have a ability for a subdomain on each of these (assets.domain.xyz, domain.xyz), but I can't for the life of me seem to have both enabled.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    UseCanonicalName Off
    VirtualDocumentRoot "/www/%1.0.%-1.0/public"
    ServerName %1.0.%-1.0
    ServerAlias %1.0.%-1.0.*.xip.io

    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    UseCanonicalName Off
    VirtualDocumentRoot "/www/%2.0.%-1.0/assets"
    ServerName assets.%2.0.%-1.0
    ServerAlias assets.%2.0.%-1.0.*.xip.io
</VirtualHost>
```

Which ever is first works and the latter is skipped over.

Is this even possible? I'd like to prevent myself from having to duplicate this every time I have a new domain pointing to me and trying to avoid writing any scripts.

**EDIT** 
I'm trying to get it so I can have two generic mappings like below:

```
domain.dev        => /www/domain.dev/public
assets.domain.dev => /www/domain/assets
```

If its simpler to just have /public/assets then i'd be happy with that as this is only going to be serving static content anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only way i've got it working is by adding a non-dynamic vhost to handle the subdomain.

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAlias %-2.0.%-1.0
        VirtualDocumentRoot /www/%-2.0.%-1.0/public

        <Directory />
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>

    <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAlias assets.*
        VirtualDocumentRoot /www/%-2.0.%-1.0/assets

        <Directory />
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
            AllowOverride None
            SetHandler default-handler
            php_flag engine Off
        </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
```

This will do for now as at least I don't have to repeat it to often.